# Implementing Array into Bubblesort

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, implementation

I've been trying to find ways of using this array in the bubble sort function later on but it won't be recognised in context for some reason, all I want to do is find a way to implement all the values from the text file (array) into variable a on bubble sort. I've tried using a regular string array to read the text file but this proved unsuccessful as I could not use any operators on the string array. Happy to take any alternative solutions to mine and I'd greatly appreciate any help with this thank you. :)

```
                    int[] a = { 3, 0, 2, 5, -1, 4, 1 };
                    int t;
                    Console.WriteLine("Original array :");
                    foreach (int aa in a)
                        Console.Write(aa + " ");
                    for (int p = 0; p <= a.Length - 2; p++)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i <= a.Length - 2; i++)
                        {
                            if (a[i] > a[i + 1])
                            {
                                t = a[i + 1];
                                a[i + 1] = a[i];
                                a[i] = t;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Sorted array :");
                    foreach (int aa in a)
                        Console.Write(aa + " ");
                    Console.Write("\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (userAnswer == "1")
{
    int[] a = { 3, 0, 2, 5, -1, 4, 1 };
    int t;
    Console.WriteLine("Original array :");
    foreach (int aa in a)
        Console.Write(aa + " ");
    for (int p = 0; p <= a.Length - 2; p++)
    {
        for (int i = p+1; i <= a.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] < a[p])
            {
                t = a[i];
                a[i] = a[p];
                a[p] = t;
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Sorted array :");
    foreach (int aa in a)
        Console.Write(aa + " ");
    Console.Write("\n");
}
```

Your sorting code should be as above.
Please note that, this is to sort ascending.

Comment: Ah thank you so much! So what I had originally for the sorting code was descending? And how would I take my array and replace the line: int[] a = { 3, 0, 2, 5, -1, 4, 1 }, with the array values?

Comment: if (a[i] > a[p])
Change the 'if condition' as this to sort descending.

Comment: how would I go about to adding the array from the for loop to the sorting algorithm? It sorts the example set numbers: 3, 0, 2, 5 etc but the array has 256 numbers I want this algorithm to sort